# CAB deleted from autoinstall after cold reboot

Tags: windows-ce

i have a dolphin 7600 with windows CE.

normally when i put CAB files in  the folder Auto-install and do a cold reboot they're automatically installed and they still exist in the folder.
but now they're installed but i find the folder empty afterwords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that the user overwrote the `IPSM` folder of the dolphin 7600 with one he got from dolphin 9500 i found that the problem was in the AUTOINSTALL.EXE it was responsible for deleting the CAB files after installation.
i downloaded the proper AUTOINSTALL.EXE file from this website http://hool.ee/ and put it in the ISPM folder

Answer (score 0):

Mark the CAB files as read-only and wceload.exe will no longer be able to delete them after installation.